# Nothing shows up when "echo" $_GET rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to to create a users profile, it is suposed to get the id from the url, then get all the info from the user with that id.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $userID = $_GET["id"];
  $getUserNames = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$userID";
  $result = $conn->query("getUserNames");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo "<h1>";
    echo $row["username"];
    echo "</h1>";
    echo "<p><b>Name: </b>";
    echo $row["username"];
    echo "</p>";
   echo "<p><b>Password: </b>***** (<a href='#'>Change Password</a>)</p>";
  } else {
if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  echo "<h1>";
  echo $_SESSION["username"];
  echo "</h1>";
  echo "<p><b>Name: </b>";
  echo $_SESSION["username"];
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<p><b>Password: </b>***** (<a href='#'>Change Password</a>)</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>You need to be logged in too see your profile!";
}
}?>
```

I get nothing from the echo and there is no error.

Please help!

Comment: *"no error"* - No error checking. `$result = $conn->query("getUserNames");` which would have thrown you an `undefined constant getUserNames` notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Not a constant, it's just a string

Comment: @u_mulder I was close. Do I still get a cee-gar? A nice Cohiba perhaps?

Comment: Smoking's bad... mmmkay.

Comment: @Mike The Vatican says sex is bad too, but I don't live there (anymore).

Comment: Oh... I clearly remember somebody using it this way... Weird.

Comment: You have an sql injection and you also get 500 internal error therefore no output. Do turn on error output.

Comment: `$result = $conn->query("$getUserNames");` there, we're done here ;-) or `$result = $conn->query($getUserNames);`

Comment: ^^ What he said, but without the unnecessary quotation marks. @Fred-ii- is tired. Too many cigars have hurt his brain.

Comment: Agh you corrected it. Nevermind. I'll go back to lurking.

Comment: @Mike which I corrected *before* your comment ;-) I think I'm going to go and pay myself a nice cappuccino now. both work though, as long as it's inside double quotes and not singles.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Comments don't auto-refresh when they've been updated... I didn't notice it until I posted mine.

Comment: @Mike No worries Mike, *cheers* would be cool though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error at `$conn->query("getUserNames");` which should be: `$conn->query($getUserNames);`

The complete new code with the fix looks like this:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $userID = $_GET["id"];
  $getUserNames = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$userID";
  $result = $conn->query($getUserNames);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo "<h1>";
    echo $row["username"];
    echo "</h1>";
    echo "<p><b>Name: </b>";
    echo $row["username"];
    echo "</p>";
   echo "<p><b>Password: </b>***** (<a href='#'>Change Password</a>)</p>";
  } else {
if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  echo "<h1>";
  echo $_SESSION["username"];
  echo "</h1>";
  echo "<p><b>Name: </b>";
  echo $_SESSION["username"];
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<p><b>Password: </b>***** (<a href='#'>Change Password</a>)</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>You need to be logged in too see your profile!";
}
}?>
```